# toolbar not appearing in pre lollipop devices

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat, android-toolbar, drawerlayout

Toolbar is not appearing on pre lollipop devices. I'm using drawer layout with toolbar. The same toolbar works on other activities but not when used along with drawer layout.

**Activity with drawer layout and toolbar**

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


              setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

                {

                    /*supportChatImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.homeSupportChatImageButton);
                    orderImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.homeOrderImageButton);*/
                    headerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.homeHeaderTextView);
                    slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.homeSlidingTabLayout);
                    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.homeViewPager);
                    headerBackgroundImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.homeHeaderBackgroundImageView);

                    mainContentLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.homeScreenMainContentLayout);
                    hamburgerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                    hamburgerLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.hamburgerProfileLayout);
                    hamburgerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hamburgerListView);
                    hamburgerMenu = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.hamburgerMenu);
                    GetHamburgerListItems();
                    HamburgerListAdapter hamburgerListAdapter = new HamburgerListAdapter(this, hamburgerListItems);
                    hamburgerListView.setAdapter(hamburgerListAdapter);

                    userProfileImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userProfileImageView);
                    userProfileNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userProfileNameTextView);

                    if(StorageManager.read(this, "userProfile", new TypeToken<UserProfile>() {}.getType()) != null) {
                        UserProfile userProfile = (UserProfile) StorageManager.read(this, "userProfile", new TypeToken<UserProfile>() {}.getType());
                        userProfileNameTextView.setText(userProfile.getFullName());
                    }
                    else {
                        userProfileNameTextView.setText("Login / Sign up");
                    }

                    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/GothamRnd-Medium.otf");
                    slidingTabLayout.setTypeface(typeface);
                    slidingTabLayout.setTextColor("#FFFFFF");
                }

                if(Utilities.IsCitySelected(this)) {
                    selectedCity = Utilities.GetSelectedCity(this);
                }
                else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreenActivity.this, ErrorInternetActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("error", "error");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }


                toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
                toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_image_dehaze);
                toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.home_screen_menu);
                toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

                actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, hamburgerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                        syncState();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                        syncState();
                    }
                };

                hamburgerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
                hamburgerLayout.setDrawerListener(this);

        hamburgerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    publ

    ic void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                    SelectItemFromDrawer(position);
                }
            });

            hamburgerLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(Utilities.IsUserLoggedIn(HomeScreenActivity.this)) {
                        hamburgerLayout.closeDrawer(hamburgerMenu);
                        isLinkClicked = true;
                        position = 2;
                    }
                    else {
                        hamburgerLayout.closeDrawer(hamburgerMenu);
                        isLinkClicked = true;
                        position = 3;
                    }
}

                }
            });
```

**Activity - XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeScreenActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeScreenMainContentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/main_toolbar"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.6">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/homeHeaderBackgroundImageView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="42dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                            android:gravity="right">

                            <!--<ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/homeSupportChatImageButton"
                                android:layout_width="36dp"
                                android:layout_height="36dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/ic_help"
                                android:visibility="visible" />

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/homeOrderImageButton"
                                android:layout_width="36dp"
                                android:layout_height="36dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_orders" />-->

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <com.misc.TextView
                            android:id="@+id/homeHeaderTextView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/home_screen_header_text"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="24sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            app:fontName="@string/gotham_bold_reg" />

                        <com.misc.SlidingTabLayout
                            android:id="@+id/homeSlidingTabLayout"
                            fontPath="fonts/GothamRnd-Medium.otf"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"></com.misc.SlidingTabLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.40"
                android:background="#FFFFFF">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/homeViewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/hamburgerMenu"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <!-- Profile Box -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hamburgerProfileLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="144dp"
            android:background="@color/lo_orange"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userProfileImageView"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_person_blue" />

            <com.misc.TextView
                android:id="@+id/userProfileNameTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                app:fontName="@string/gotham_medium_reg"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/hamburgerListView"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/hamburgerProfileLayout"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**main_toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/lo_orange"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.misc.TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolBarTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fontName="@string/gotham_medium_reg"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <com.misc.TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolBarSubTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fontName="@string/gotham_light_reg"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**style.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColorHintInverse">@color/lo_orange</item>
        <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_orange</item>-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/lo_orange</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/lo_orange</item>

        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    </style>
```

Comment: Put the toolbar after the LinearLayout so it is drawn over content. You don't percieve this error on Lollipop because elevation overrides this behavior.

Comment: @EugenPechanec: Brilliant !! Works Great !! Thanks a lot. You can put that as an answer.. And can you explain in detail how positioning the toolbar works? Need some clarity on understanding it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a common issue becoming less apparent when testing on Lollipop or later.

When using standard layouts (such as `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc.) the default behavior is that child views get drawn in order they are added or inflated.

The fix would look similar to this:

```
<FrameLayout>
     <!-- Content will be drawn first - below the toolbar. -->
     <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/main_content" />
     <!-- Toolbar will be drawn next - above the content. -->
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
</FrameLayout>
```

However since Lollipop the `android:elevation` attribute can override this behavior. Since elevation defines precise position along the Z axis views with higher elevation values will be drawn above those with lower elevation values.